# Is it possible to Unit Test a Coded WebTest request and assert based on the response?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have written a framework for performance testing in C# for Visual Studio Web Performance Testing.

I have written a Unit Test class to test the base classes but I would also like to add a unit test each request so I can ensure the WebTests are working as expected by adding a WebTestPlugin to obtain the Response Status Code.

So far I have been unsuccessful and before I pull my hair out I thought I would ask if it is possible, unfortunately Google has not answered my question.

I can provide code if required but just imagine trying to write a unit test for a webtest yield return result.

Thanks in advanced for any help given.

As Requested, Here is my code.

UnitTest

```
public void ContentAuthor_GetToken_GetRequest() {
        foreach (WebTestRequest myRequest in (new CWebTestExecutor(m_scenarioData))) {
            //TODO: Assert Status Code
        }
    }
```

WebTestPlugin & WebtTest Executor

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Builder.Request;
using Data;
using Library;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;

namespace PerformanceTest.Requests.Library.UnitTests {
internal class CWebTestExecutor : WebTest {
    private readonly CScenarioData m_scenarioData;
    public CWebTestExecutorPlugin WebTestExecutorPlugin;

    public CWebTestExecutor(CScenarioData scenarioData) : this() {
        m_scenarioData = scenarioData;
    }
    public CWebTestExecutor() {
        WebTestExecutorPlugin = new CWebTestExecutorPlugin();
        PreAuthenticate = true;
    }

    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator() {
        PostRequest += WebTestExecutorPlugin.PostRequest;
        yield return new CBuildRequest().BuildStructure(new CRequest().GetToken(m_scenarioData));
    }
}
public class CWebTestExecutorPlugin : WebTestPlugin {
    public HttpStatusCode PageResult { get; private set; }

    public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e) {
        PageResult = e.Response.StatusCode;
    }
}
```

}

Now, when this executes the executor works correctly and the plugin is associated however executing the yield return does not trigger the PostRequest Event so I cannot get the Response Status code.

If this does not explain the issue than please let me know and I will try provide more details.

Comment: Providing some code samples will help readers get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I will add them now, just need to remote to my computer.

Comment: Code now added to question

Comment: nice questions, it's a pity there is no answer...

Comment: Anybody have an idea how a `WebTest`-object is executed? The code has to be somewhere, but seems to be hard-to-find. Eyeballing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting` doesn't seem to yield any usable results.

Comment: Ok, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/988592/1548275 it seems like the actual runner-code is in `MSTest.exe` making this very very hard.